# What is the 'E' in `RAISE NOTICE E'msg %', mymsg`

Tags: postgresql, notice, raise

What is the 'E' in `RAISE NOTICE E'msg %', mymsg`?

I've seen it used in various Postgres tutorial pages, even in [Postgres documentation itself](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CALL-STACK), but I can't find an actual *explanation* of what it is or does.

It's usually used with messages that use `GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS`, but the message itself only looks to me like a normal
`RAISE NOTICE 'foo: %, bar: %',foo_value, bar_value;`
type of message where the foo and bar values are simply assigned to the specific diagnostic values in the lines before the RAISE NOTICE.

So, what's magic about the `E'...'`?

Comment: @zegarek (correctly) noted that my examples are not particularly relevant to the examples in my question.  Part of me feels like I should edit my question, but the question's motivation was borne in part out of lack of understanding the relevancy of `E'...'`.  So, I'm choosing to leave it unedited, with just a note here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation about what goes after the [`RAISE`*`level`*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html):

> After ***`level`*** if any, you can specify a ***`format`*** string (which must be a simple string literal, not an expression).

Another name for a *string literal* is a *string constant* [documented here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS). Those can use C-like backslash escape sequences: [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE)

> PostgreSQL also accepts “escape” string constants, which are an extension to the SQL standard. An escape string constant is specified by writing the letter **`E`** (upper or lower case) just before the opening single quote, e.g., **`E'foo'`**. (When continuing an escape string constant across lines, write **`E`** only before the first opening quote.) Within an escape string, a backslash character (**`\`**) begins a C-like *backslash escape* sequence, in which the combination of backslash and following character(s) represent a special byte value, as shown in [Table 4.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-BACKSLASH-TABLE).
>
> **Table 4.1. Backslash Escape Sequences**
>
> | Backslash Escape Sequence | Interpretation |
> | --- | --- |
> | \b | backspace |
> | \f | form feed |
> | \n | newline |
> | \r | carriage return |
> | \t | tab |
> | \***o***, \***oo***, \***ooo*** (***o*** = 0–7) | octal byte value |
> | \x***h***, \x***hh*** (***h*** = 0–9, A–F) | hexadecimal byte value |
> | \u***xxxx***, \U***xxxxxxxx*** (***x*** = 0–9, A–F) | 16 or 32-bit hexadecimal Unicode character value |

'E' in `RAISE NOTICE E'msg %', mymsg` in your opening example is just syntax noise - not particularly magical, not very useful.

- If `mymsg` argument contains newlines, or anything requiring some special action to put it there, it will be inserted in place of `%` placeholder regardless of whether you use `E'...'` or not.
- If `mymsg` argument contains backslash escape sequences, those won't be interpreted as such.

In the doc you linked it does make sense since the `\n` sequence is in the literal/constant:

```sql
GET DIAGNOSTICS stack = PG_CONTEXT;
RAISE NOTICE E'--- Call Stack ---\n%', stack;
```

Note that `stack` variable also holds newlines of its own and those end up being inserted into the message even if there's no `E` out front.

---

[Cheatsheet](https://dbfiddle.uk/Qafh4huq):

```
do $r$ begin raise exception '1\n2%4' , '\n3\n'; end $r$;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  1\n2\n3\n4
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 1 at RAISE
> ```

```
do $r$ begin raise exception E'1\n2%4' , '\n3\n'; end $r$;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  1
> 2\n3\n4
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 1 at RAISE
> ```

```
do $r$ begin raise exception '1\n2%4' , E'\n3\n'; end $r$;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  1\n2
> 3
> 4
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 1 at RAISE
> ```

```
do $r$ begin raise exception E'1\n2%4' , E'\n3\n'; end $r$;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 1 at RAISE
> ```

Comment: They will be if `mymsg` uses `E'...'` also.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I get your point but I need to draw a line: if you declare `mymsg` to be `E'\n'` it will then be immediately interpreted and hold an actual newline, not a backslash escape sequence denoting one. My point stands: 'E' in `RAISE NOTICE E'msg %', mymsg` makes no sense because if `mymsg` contains a newline, it will be passed regardless of the 'E'. If `mymsg` instead contains a backslash escape sequence for a newline, it will not be interpreted when inserted in place of a `%` placeholder in an `E'...'` string constant in a `RAISE` *`level`* ***`format`***. I'll add that for clarity.

Comment: Thank you!  The 'Constants' documentation in [4.1.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) was exactly the piece I was missing, especially the 4.1.2.2 subsection you linked to.  Moreover, I never new it was so easy to format numeric values to hex and oct!